# adding loadbar from inside the function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom loader that i have made in css and  this is my html :

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

and i would like to add this just after the:("Testing your internet connection quality...")

```
function InitiateSpeedDetection() {
    ShowProgressMessage("Testing your internet connection quality...");
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[2].removeAttribute("class");
    window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 1);
};
```

I have tried this.

```
var x = document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML;
function InitiateSpeedDetection() {
    ShowProgressMessage("Testing your internet connection quality...");
    document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementsByTagName("li")[2].removeAttribute("class");
    window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 1);
};
```

It did not work. 
Additional to my question how can i change default timeout.

```
window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 1);
```

Comment: Can you provide full example, not small parts of code?

Comment: Sure it was just too long I did not want to mess. But I made jsfiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/8u4afnsL/

Answer (score 1):

`.setTimeout` uses milliseconds, not seconds. To look anything you should set your timeout to larger value, for example 3 seconds.

```
window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the showing/hiding of the loader, it's hard to tell for sure without looking at the rest of your code, but you can try the following:

1. Add `display: none` to the CSS of `.loader`
2. Inside your `InitiateSpeedDetection()` function, do something like:

   ```
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display = 'initial';
   ```
3. Change it back to `display: hidden` when you want to hide the loader

Does that work?

Comment: I could not make it work yet , but i am working on it. Thank you for your time.